# Why use dependency injection in angularjs for controllers?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I came across this tutorial.

http://justinvoelkel.me/laravel-angularjs-part-two-login-and-authentication/

The author used dependency injection to inject the login controller in app.js like this.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('blogApp',[
'ngRoute',
//Login
'LoginCtrl'
]);
app.run(function(){

});

//This will handle all of our routing
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$routeProvider.when('/',{
templateUrl:'js/templates/login.html',
controller:'LoginController'
});

});
```

The login controller file looks like this.

LoginController.js:

```
var login = angular.module('LoginCtrl',[]);

login.controller('LoginController',function($scope){
$scope.loginSubmit = function(){
console.dir($scope.loginData);
}
});
```

I don't understand why the dependency injection is required here.

Here is my version of app.js and LoginController.js which works perfectly fine.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('ilapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });

}]);
```

LoginController.js:

```
angular.module('ilapp').controller('LoginController', [function () {
    this.loginSubmit = function () {
        console.dir(this.loginData);
    };
}]);
```

Is there any advantage to the author's approach? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, both are correct way and it should work but you can choose any one method depends upon your project.

**Approach 1**

In your question, the first approach is `modular way`. Means, you can register a `LoginController` controller in a new module `LoginCtrl`. Here module name `LoginCtrl` is confusing. you can change the name as `loginModule`. This approach is helpful for you to `organize the files structure` for your `big application`. Also, look this post [Angular - Best practice to structure modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621581/angular-best-practice-to-structure-modules)

```
var login = angular.module('loginModule',[]);

login.controller('LoginController',function($scope){
 $scope.loginSubmit = function(){
 console.dir($scope.loginData);
 }
});

var app = angular.module('blogApp',[
 'ngRoute',
 'loginModule'
]);
app.run(function(){
});

//This will handle all of our routing
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
 $routeProvider.when('/',{
 templateUrl:'js/templates/login.html',
 controller:'LoginController'
});

});
```

**Approach 2**

If your application contains `minimal pages` and no need to `split multiple modules`, then you can write all your controllers in `app.js` itself